# How to count the leaf elements of assocaitive/nested array

Tags: php

I have been trying to count the last leaf node elements in a array. 
Im thinking along the lines of:

- Getting a simple array of leaf elements from the testArray using: 'array_walk_recursive'.
- Count elements in the new array using: 'array_count_values'.

Im unsure how to get a simple list array from 'array_walk_recursive', i just get a long string of values....or is there a better way of achieving this result?

DESIRED RESULT:

```
flammable = 1
irritant = 2 
toxic = 3
```

PHP:

```
$testArray = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => toxic
        [1] => irritant
        [3] => flammable
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => toxic
        [1] => irritant
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => toxic
    )
);

array_walk_recursive($testArray, function(&$value) 
{
    echo 'string = '.$value;
    print_r(newArray);              //How can i get this new array list?
});

 $counts = array_count_values($newArray); //and use this to count values?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the numbers should show up in the `$groups` array.

```
$groups = array();

array_walk_recursive($testArray, function(&$value) use (&$groups)
{
    if (isset($groups[$value])) {
        $groups[$value]++;
    } else {
        $groups[$value] = 1;
    }
});

print_r($groups);
```

Comment: Im just getting a blank array result using this?

Comment: @Orbitall Ye, forgot to set `$groups` as a reference.

Comment: Cheers, thats way more simple than what i was atempting!